# Pytorch autoencoder print accuracy positional argument error

Tags: python, pytorch, classification

I got this autoencoder

```
class AE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AE,self).__init__()
        self.encoder_hidden_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=kwargs["input_shape"], out_features=128
        )
        self.encoder_output_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=128
        )
        self.decoder_hidden_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=128
        )
        self.decoder_output_layer = nn.Linear(
            in_features=128, out_features=kwargs["input_shape"]
        )

    def forward(self, features):
        activation = self.encoder_hidden_layer(features)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        code = self.encoder_output_layer(activation)
        code = torch.sigmoid(code)
        activation = self.decoder_hidden_layer(code)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        activation = self.decoder_output_layer(activation)
        reconstructed = torch.sigmoid(activation)
        return reconstructed
```

and I am trying to build a accuracy calculator

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch_features in test_loader:
        batch_features = batch_features[0]
        test_examples = batch_features.view(-1, 784)
        reconstruction = model(test_examples)
        
        images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
        print(labels)
        
        outputs_auto = AE(images.to(device))
        _, predicted_auto = torch.max(outputs_auto.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted_auto == labels).sum().item()
        break
    print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```

but it shows this type of error. I have tried some modification of the code but it failed. I am new to autoencoder

```
---> 21         outputs_auto = AE(images.to(device))
     22         _, predicted_auto = torch.max(outputs_auto.data, 1)
     23         total += labels.size(0)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I just want to print accuracy in percent. If you need more code please ask to edit this question

Answer (score 0):

When calling `outputs_auto = AE(images.to(device))` you are calling `AE`'s `__init__` function. While what you should do is call the module's forward function (i.e. `__call__`). Therefore, you should first initialize your autoencoder, then call it with the desired input. You also need to provide the `input_shape` as per the implementation of the `AE` module. For example you could do:

```
autoencoder = AE(input_shape=100).to(device)
```

Here's to get you started with the test loop and accuracy measurement with dummy data:

```
test_set = TensorDataset(torch.rand(16, 28, 28), torch.rand(16, 1))
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set)
 
correct = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in test_loader:
        images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
        images = images.reshape(images.shape[0], -1)
        
        outputs_auto = autoencoder(images)
        predicted_class = torch.argmax(outputs_auto)
        correct += (predicted_class == labels).sum().item()
print('Accuracy of the network %.1f%%' % (100*correct/len(test_loader)))
```

Replace `test_loader` with the relevant data loader. Also change the `input_shape` to the correct size.

Comment: I use mnist. I changed input_shape to 784 and it runs but shows 0% accuracy

Comment: Are you training your model?

Comment: Yes, I train  batch_size = 512 epochs = 20 learning_rate = 1e-3

Comment: I mean, that's a complete different problem, are you plotting your training/validation loss?

Comment: Do you mean epoch training loss?

Comment: I use [this](https://medium.com/pytorch/implementing-an-autoencoder-in-pytorch-19baa22647d1) tutorial

Comment: Are you not able to run the provided code?

Comment: `# add the mini-batch training loss to epoch loss
        loss += train_loss.item()` I think you mean this line of code. When I run the code of the tutorial everything looks fine but I have tried to modify the code by adding the accuracy calculation lines

Comment: The code you provided in the original post is not correct and is not the same as the one you've given me by link.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/AFAgarap/4f8a8d8edf352271fa06d85ba0361f26) link must be the whole code of the first link. I have added `AE,self` in `super(AE,self)` and some lines of code in `with torch.no_grad():`. I am a bit confused what do you mean is not correct? Has the tutorial mistakes?

Comment: No, what I mean is the code you provided in the original post (above) is not the same code as the code on that link. For instance you wrote `AE(images.to(device))` which is wrong as I showed you in my answer. You have modified/added code that wasn't originally in the tutorial source code.

Comment: Check to [this](https://pastebin.com/Xr2AVsMC) link my code as I run it